# Accepting an answer when more of them are needed to solve the issue

Tags: discussion

I apologize for the bad title, I'm not sure how to put it in one sentence.

The issue is, I have two answers and both need to be 'applied' to solve the problem and neither mentions the other one (they are two completely different steps). In addition, I have found a better alternative to the first one (updating a dependency instead of relying on the workaround; however, update process isn't quite obvious). If I only do what one answer says, I'll still have an issue, albeit a different one.

What's the right thing to do in this situation? I guess I could write an answer referencing the two steps and provide an alternative for the first and accept that one, but I'm not sure will that be all right to the original answerers. On the other hand, both are partial answers and neither actually solves my problem on its own.

Question in... well, question: [Play Cannot connect to database [default]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323835/play-cannot-connect-to-database-default/)

Comment: There are a couple ways you can do this- You can comment on both that they helped with the addition of the other answer, or, as you've already suggested, you can write up your own answer that includes the better alternative you found. This won't necessarily be _wrong_ though you definitely should point to the other answers and attribute the credit to them. You can even make your answer "Community Wiki" by clicking a checkbox below the answer field. This will prevent you from gaining reputation from the answer, if you feel bad about that.